# Multitouch for 3x3 Buttons

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am working on a hobby project to learn more about ios programming.

My main view has 9 buttons (3x3 grid).

What I need is a way to know if the user pressed 2 or 1 buttons and which buttons these were.

I am making a memory game where sometimes the user is required to press 2 of the buttons at the same time (One after another will not suffice).

I need to be able to make the distinction between the user pressing 1 of the 9 buttons or 2.

If they press more than 2 that is considered cheating and will count as a strike.

I have been reading this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html

But I'm not sure how to go about it.

How do I link up my 9 buttons into 1 nice multitouch event that can tell me:
Button 3 only was pressed.
or
Buttons 4 and 5 were pressed.
?

From there the logic is perfectly clear, but I'm having trouble with IOS multitouch events.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The touch interface is sensitive enough that humans will not be able to press two buttons at the "exact" same time.

What you'll probably have to do is see if they touched two and only two buttons within a "reasonable" window of time to be considered simultaneous.

One approach would be to log the exact moment each button is pressed with a `NSDate* press = [NSDate date];` call, and then compare the presses with `NSTimeInterval* interval = [press2 timeIntervalSinceDate press1];`

Some clever batching of time intervals and a bit of conditional logic later and you should have a good test of "simultaneous" presses.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the docs it should work like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

methods of the parent view

In the (UIEvent *)event U should have NSSet of UITouchs

```
NSArray *arrTouches = [[event allTouches] allObjects]
```

iterate through array and:

```
UITouch *touch ---
touch.view -> check if this is button
```

should be the view in witch touh happened